# Updating weights python for REINFORCE policy gradient method

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, implementation

All,

I am trying to implement REINFORCE(williams) algorithm. This is a policy gradient reinforcement learning algorithm.

I am using python, and hope to use keras.

The pseduocode I am using is as follows:

1. from the initial state, run a simulation of the policy, till end.
2. the actions taken . are generated from (in my scenario) a NN.
3. We update the weights by: learning rate * derivative(log policy) * V
4. We are using V as an unbiased sample of Q.

[image: This is the algorithm I am using]

V is defined as the average reward being at a particular state.

In keras, we can build a neural network, and then update the weights by taking weights + (log of actions * V)? Is this correct?

How would I manually update the weights, I appreciate that you can extract the weights from keras sequential models, but there is also a derivative function.

Maybe I have misunderstood the algorithm, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.